# How to send multiple related values from my html form to server via $_POST?

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I was going to use jQuery to clone the input field when I click a button to make another field, but I was thinking of doing:

`Page One, Page Two, Page Three` <- then send that as one `$_POST` to the server and have it take each page and break on the "," comma then for each insert in to my POSTS table.

Any idea on how I would do that? Would I use explode()? Then inside a `foreach()` run a query for each item in the field.

So if there were 5 pages typed in separated by commas, it would run five times using the `foreach()`.

```
for each(){
  EXECUTE SQL HERE
}
```

Does that sound like it would be the best way of going about it?

Comment: what are you trying to do? pagination? what are the buttons for?

Comment: Not for pagination, for I can type in:

"About, Contact, Products" in to an input then insert EACH of those separated by comma and place them in my PAGES table, so run three different queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the `name` attribute of the `input` element to the name of an array, e.g. `foo[]`, you'll be able to access it as such when processing the `$_POST` vars, e.g.

```
<input name="foo[]" type="text"/>
<input name="foo[]" type="text"/>
```

becomes two iterations of:

```
foreach ($_POST['foo'] as $foo) {
    // process $foo
}
```

Answer (score 0):

explode and foreach sound good.

But as Click Upvote indicated: is it for pagination? 'cause then there could be a betetr way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
<input type="text" name="list[]" />
```

Everytime you need a new input box you can do

```
$(some_element).append( '<input type="text" name="list[]" />' );
```

or sth similar with jQuery.

Then you have an array instead of a single value in your PHP `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable. So you can use `$_POST['list']` in foreach.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking, I can type in:

Home, Products, About, Contact

Into a input field, then my php can break it apart using the comma and insert each of those page titles in my PAGES table.

Run the SQL within the foreach.

Thoughts?